# converting virtual path to actual web path in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a virtual path (example:  "~/Images/Banner.jpg") and I want to make that an absolute web path (example:  "/ApplicationRoot/Images/Banner.jpg").  There is a method that will do this, I believe in a class called something like HTTPUtility or similar name.  Though ever time I need this method, it takes me hours searching for it.  It would be greatly appreciated if someone could post the proper method to do this so I can favorite this for easy access in the future.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoelBeckham You are right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("yourRelativePath");
```

There you go :)

Comment: I actually had the same problem untill I made my own PathHelper class for the asp.net mvc framework :p

Comment: Hehe, yet another place to do this! I guess they all end up at the same place.

Comment: This was exactly the method I keep forgetting.. I don't know why it's so hard for me to remember or find this one.

Comment: Thank you again..  It has been a year, I still can't remember that command, and I still go to here every time to remember it.

Answer (score 13):

There are various ways that are available in ASP.NET that we can use to resolve relative paths to absolute Urls -

1) Request.ApplicationPath
2) System.Web.VirtualPathUtility
3) Page.ResolveUrl
4) Page.ResolveClientUrl

Here's a article that explains the difference between the various ways to resolving paths in ASP.NET -

[Different approaches for resolving URLs in ASP.NET](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html)

Comment: Um.  I don't think there **is** a `Page.ResolveClientUrl`.  The method exists in `Control` apparently: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
Control.ResolveClientUrl(url)
```

or

```
Control.ResolveUrl(url)
```

Whichever one you need (honestly I dont know the difference, as both seem to return mostly the same, perhaps someone can illuminate me :)  ).

Comment: How do you make your verry first line a "code" line?
In preview it looks all biscuits and milk, but when I submit it becomes an unformatted line again :s

Comment: I didnt have that problem. Using FF.