# Display a PDF or DOC from database in an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, pdf

hi i want to display a PDF file or .DOC or an image saved in my Data Base into my ASP.net page. 
i tryed this code but without sucess. have any one an idea how can i do it ?

```
  <object type="application/pdf" data="~/Protected/docs/CV_Zied_JOUINI.pdf" width="400"     height="300">
<param name="movie" value="~/Protected/docs/CV_Zied_JOUINI.pdf" />
<img src="~/Protected/docs/CV_Zied_JOUINI.pdf" alt="" width="200" height="100" />
```

Comment: The path to your files isn't correct. The `~/` is virtual path syntax only intended for use on the server side. You'll need to use something like described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353165/converting-virtual-path-to-actual-web-path-in-asp-net) to convert it to a path usable by the client.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to display a PDF file or .DOC or an image **saved in my Data Base**
>   into my ASP.net page

If a file is saved in Database, it is normally in Binary format.

If so, you need a **File Handler** in order to display those Binary Data back to client 
browser.

For example,

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];

        // Let say you get the file data from database based on id
        // ...
        var fileData = new byte[] { ... };

        string fileName = "PDF_FILENAME.pdf";
        context.Response.Clear();
        // Need to return appropriate ContentType for different type of file.
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
           "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileData.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.Write(fileData);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
<a href="/FileHandler.ashx?id=1">My File</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i will explain my question. im making a website using ASP.NET and i made a directory called docs (/Protected/docs/) inside my web project. I gave the possibility to user to upload file, then i want to give him the possibility to view this uploded file inside another page before downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code in action, you might consider placing the `object` tag inside a `div`. I'm not convinced you need the `param` and `img` tags for a PDF though. Try this,

```
<div> <object data="~/Protected/docs/CV_Zied_JOUINI.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"> alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a> </object> </div>
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment on the question, you can't use the `~/` syntax on the client side.

Comment: @mason, Right, I used the code the OP had for the 'data' attribute. Sorry about that.

Comment: @mason thank you for your help. i put the code inside <div> and i changed the link to a file with absolute path but is the same thing. it just displays a grau square.

Comment: @user3773380 Is the path to the file correct? If you manually navigate there, do you see the file? Have you tried implementing either a file handler or generic handler as Win and my answers described?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant a relational database instead of just the file system (your question was ambiguous).

1. Create a [Generic Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332579/what-is-generic-handler-in-asp-net-and-its-use) (.ashx). This handler should accept a query string parameter specifying what the identity of the file to retrieve is. This might be a filename or ID, it depends on how you've configured your database.
2. The generic handler should retrieve the file from the database as a byte array, along with any meta data such as content type.
3. The generic handler should set its response headers to the appropriate content type using `Response.ContentType` for the file it is returning, and write the file to the response using `Response.BinaryWrite()`.
4. The paths in your `<object>` or `<img>` elements in the HTML should point to the generic handler, making sure to pass the identity of the requested file with a query string parameter, ex: `fileretriever.ashx?document=XXX-XXX` where `XXX-XXX` is the identify of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all. I used this code and it's work

```
<iframe src="/Protected/docs/CV_Zied_JOUINI.pdf" width="1320px" height="1500px"></iframe>
```

thank you :)